# Converting string array to list: double brackets

Tags: java, arrays, jlist

I use this part of the code to get the select items from a jlist into a string list. I get the following result:

```
[[String1, String2, String3,...]]
```

How can I avoid the double []? Thanks

```
static List<String> strlist = new ArrayList<String>();

public class tog {

        List<String> strlisttemp = new ArrayList<String>();

        final JList list = new JList(strlisttemp.toArray());
        list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);

        final ListSelectionListener listSelectionListener = new ListSelectionListener() {
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {

                String lstr = list.getSelectedValuesList().toString();
            System.out.println(lstr);
                strlist = Arrays.asList(lstr.split("\\s*,\\s*"));

            }
        };

        list.addListSelectionListener(listSelectionListener);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, list, "Select", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

        System.out.println(strlist);

}
```

**This is the part that has problem: When I print lstr it works properly [...]. When I use this:**

```
strlist = Arrays.asList(lstr.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
```

**Then System.out.println(strlist); prints double brackets**

Comment: please format your code, it's almost unreadable

Comment: I think your missing the point `list.getSelectedValuesList().toString()`. You are not using the generic interface for `JList` and you are parsing the `String` when you can get a `List<E>` from `getSelectedValuesList()`.

Comment: Works fine otherwise:

        String str = "abc,def";
        System.err.println(Arrays.asList(str.split("\\s*,\\s*")));

Comment: What do you mean it works fine? Strlist shows the results like this [[aaa,bbb]]. I need [aaa,bbb]. @Optional

Comment: I believe the code that is vital in solving the problem is clearly readeable. @tom

Comment: I updated code and I know which line causes the problem.

Comment: Code that I posted is working fine. its printing [aaa,bbb] only

Comment: Your code doesn't compile (you are manipulating data at class level instead in code block like in methods body and `strlist` is outside of your class). Please provide code that we could use to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @user2598911 it does not  [[aaa,bbb]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're unnecessarily converting the returned `List` to its raw `String` representation, splitting that `String` into a `String[]`, then converting the `String[]` to List.

Instead, just work directly with the List which is returned.

```
package com.example.list;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

public class ListExample {
    static List<String> strlist = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> strlisttemp = new ArrayList<String>();
        strlisttemp.add("a");
        strlisttemp.add("b");
        strlisttemp.add("c");

        final JList list = new JList(strlisttemp.toArray());
        list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);

        final ListSelectionListener listSelectionListener = new ListSelectionListener() {
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {

                strlist = list.getSelectedValuesList(); // use this instead

//              String lstr = list.getSelectedValuesList().toString();
//              strlist = Arrays.asList(lstr.split("\\s*,\\s*"));

                System.out.println(strlist);
            }
        };

        list.addListSelectionListener(listSelectionListener);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, list, "Select", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);


    }
}
```

Comment: Yes but I need the info to end up a str array list. Thats why I use: strlist = Arrays.asList(lstr.split("\\s*,\\s*")); @rob

Comment: I'm not following.  Do you need it in a String[] or a List<String>?

Answer (score 2):

When you call `List.toString` it puts brackets around the result.

So you call `list.getSelectedValuesList()` and you are retrieving a `List<String>`. You call `toString()` on this which gives you `"[a, b, c, d]"`. You then split this string on the comma-space sequence and get `"[a", "b", "c", "d]"`. You put this into another list and call `toString()` on it and get another bracket around it.

It's double-bracketed because in this second list the first entry is `"[a"` and the last entry is `"d]"`!

Answer (score 1):

This is to answer your question on why you're getting the double square brackets.  For a better way to code this, see rob's answer.

```
String lstr = list.getSelectedValuesList().toString();
```

At this point, lstr == "[aaa,bbb,ccc]"

```
strlist = Arrays.asList(lstr.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
```

Now at this point, the first element of strlist will start with '[' because that is the first character of lstr, and the last element will end with ']' because that is the last character of lstr.

Now, when you go to print strlist

```
System.out.println(strlist);
```

Java will implicitly be calling list.toString(), which appends a set of square brackets when printing the list.  Since the first element in your list starts with a square bracket, and the last element ends with one, what you end up with is a double bracket at the beginning and the end